# Twitter posts counts

Tags: asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I'm using Twitterizer in my application. I want to get counts of all specific tweets. The problem is that I can search only 1 week old tweets only.

Comment: I'm confused by "counts of all specific tweets" .. Can you clarify? Are you trying to get the number of posts for a time period? Or the number of posts for a person? Or retweets of a specific tweet?

Answer (score -1):

Try the API of Topsy, called Otter API, they have their own database of all tweets.

http://code.google.com/p/otterapi/wiki/Resources#/searchcount

More info http://labs.topsy.com/widgets/otter-api/